# JavaFX select date and time and save in MySQL

Tags: javafx, datepicker, timestamp

In my project I need to select date and time when a product was created and to save it in a database. I'm making a desktop application using JavaFX and I have MySQL DB (project requirements, can't change).

My initial idea was to use `javafx.scene.control.DatePicker` for date & time input, and `java.sql.Timestamp` in the backend, but I'm unable to find a way to convert `DatePicker` value to `Timestamp` format. I need to preserve year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds.

Is there any way to do this? If not, what other data types do you suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you interfacing between JAvaFX and your database? JDBC or JPA? For JDBC all you need is `preparedStatement.set(index, Date.valueOf(datePicker.getValue()));`.

Comment: @James_D I have a class Product with Timestamp field, and ProductDAO where I'm inserting all the Product fields into DB. So basically I need to first convert DatePicker's value to Product.timeStamp. If that's not an option, I might as well pass it directly to ProductDAO, but that would be an uglier solution... Edit: I'm using JDBC

Comment: A `Timestamp` encapsulates both a date and time, so a `java.sql.Date` might make more sense. But for a `Timestamp` you can do something like `Timestamp.valueOf(datePicker.getValue().atTime(0,0))`.